# Jquery table.destroy doesn't work the first time on fire click

Tags: jquery, datatable, click, destroy

HTML code:

```
<!-- Devices List Navbar Menu -->
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="#" class="navbar-nav-link" id="deviceSearch"><i class="icon-search4 pr-1"></i> Devices</a>
</li>  <!-- END Devices List Navbar Menu -->
```

Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var alarmTable = $('#alarm_datatable').DataTable({
        //do staff
    });

    $("#deviceSearch").click(function(){
        alarmTable.destroy();
    });
});
```

The problem is that the table is destroyed only after the second click of the link with id "deviceSearch". The behavior is the same whether the click function is in or out of `$(document).ready`

At the first click the table header disappears, and at the second click the datatable disappears.

Could you help me why this happens and how to solve it?

Comment: Is it possible you have two `id="alarm_datatable"` in your HTML?

Comment: No only one html table with id="alarm_datatable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to precise `true` to remove completely the datatable:

```
$("#deviceSearch").click(function(){
    alarmTable.destroy(true);
});
```

> Completely remove the table from the DOM (true) or leave it in the DOM
> in its original plain un-enhanced HTML state (default, false).